# How to get relative path of dir?

Tags: c, unix, pwd, getcwd

I`m implementing pwd builtin in mini shell.

How could I get relative path without using environment variable "PWD"

```
(getenv("PWD"))
```

Example:

```
CWD = /tmp

getcwd("/tmp", buff, size)
```

> returns absolute location => `/private/tmp.`

How can I get `"/tmp"` in order to print in?

Comment: I think the [man page for getcwd()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd) might be of interest to you.

Comment: Can you please explain how `/tmp` and `/private/tmp` are related? Is one symlinked to the other? Or bind mounted? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do so.

When shell initialize, it stores current working directory to shell`s local variable. Shell gets cwd from **getcwd() (if enviroment variable "PWD" is not set)**
and **getenv("PWD") (if "PWD" is set)** during the initialization.

Example:
You are in /tmp (PWD=/tmp) (tmp = symbolic link)

CASE A

> zsh
>
> pwd

Result: /tmp

CASE B

> env -i zsh
>
> pwd

Result: /private/tmp